# ODE involving sin and ln

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Solve: $(D^2+2D+2)y=2^x\sin(\ln(2^x))$.

The complementary function can be easily calculated which comes out to be $c_1e^{-x}\cos x+c_2e^{-x}\sin x$.For the particular integral,the only thing I can think of is invoking wronksian method of variation of parameters which albeit would be a lot tedious. $W$ comes out to be a somewhat decent but the function on the right hand side is hard enough to integrate and merging it with other functions doesn't seem to be a good idea. So a neat approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that if $2^x = \exp(z)$ then $\sin(\ln(2^x)) = \sin(z)$

Comment: Perhaps rewrite the right side to $e^{ax}\sin(ax)$, with $a=\ln2$ not re-inserted until the end, to return to better-known patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as

$$\operatorname{Im}\Bigr((D^2+2D+2)z\Bigr) \equiv (D^2+2D+2)y_p = 2^x\sin(\log 2^x) = \operatorname{Im}\left(e^{x\log 2(1+i)}\right) $$

The function on the RHS is an eigenvector of the operator on the LHS, so we can simply do the following manipulation

$$z = \frac{1}{D^2+2D+2}\left[e^{x\log 2 (1+i)}\right] = \frac{e^{x\log 2 ( 1+ i)}}{2i\log^2 2 + 2 \log 2 (1+i) + 2}$$

$$ = \frac{e^{x\log 2 ( 1+ i)}}{2(\log 2 + 1)(1+i\log 2)}$$

This immediately gives the answer as

$$y_p = \operatorname{Im}(z) = \frac{2^{x-1}}{(\log 2 + 1)(\log^2 2 + 1)}\Bigr(\sin(\log 2^x)-\log 2 \cos(\log 2^x)\Bigr)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually I am new to differential equations. So could you please tell me how the first paragraph of your solution which involves introducing $Im$ part comes?Sorry if it is too obvious but I am new so I can't understand easily.

Comment: @madness $\operatorname{Im}$ is the imaginary part of a complex number, and it is a linear operator (i.e. $\operatorname{Im}(z_1+z_2) = \operatorname{Im}(z_1)+\operatorname{Im}(z_2)$) and it commutes with the differentiation operator, $D$, which is another linear operator. That means I can interchange the order of the two and solve the complex version of the inhomogenous differential equation and then take the imaginary part at the end to give me the answer to the original problem.

Comment: Very sorry for bothering. I actually am having trouble in understanding how $Im((D^2+2D+2)z)=(D^2+2D+2)y_p$ and $(2^x\sin(log(2^x))=Im(e^{xlog2(1+i)})$. It will be very helpful if you explain these $2$. The rest I can understand.

Comment: @madness I used a three equal sign $\equiv$ not $=$ which means I was defining it to be that way, there was nothing to be solved for. For the second one use Euler's formula to verify it for yourself.